# Is there a closed form to this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics

Here is the series in question,

```
1 + 2 + 1 + 4 +
1 + 2 + 1 + 8 +
1 + 2 + 1 + 4 +
1 + 2 + 1 + 16 +
1 + 2 + 1 + 4 +
1 + 2 + 1 + 8 +
1 + 2 + 1 + 4 +
1 + 2 + 1 + 32 + ...
```

so for example, given n = 4, the series sum is 1 + 2 + 1 + 4 = 8

I created this series inspired by the game 2048,
and I've been trying to find the closed-form with respect to n for a few hours to no avail.
Does there exist a closed-form? What's the name of this type of series?

Comment: Shouldn't the sequence of the last term in each row be $4,8,4,16,4,8,{\color{red} 4},32,\ldots$?

Comment: yea, thanks for catching my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a number of ways to approach this problem. Let me give you an idea of two ways to investigate this sort of thing. For this post, let $a(n)$ be the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence and $b(n)$ be the sum of the first $n$ terms of $a$. I doubt there's anything that might ordinarily be called a closed form, but you can certainly do better than just summing the terms.

---

**Way 1:** Look it up!

This is *exactly* the kind of question that should lead a mathematician to search on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) (the online encyclopedia of integer sequences) - if we type in the original sequence as a search query, we can find a page [here](http://oeis.org/A006520) regarding the sequence - described as "Highest power of $2$ dividing $n$." This is not super useful on its own - although, as we will see, the formal description of the sequence given in its title is useful - but there are a lot of comments beneath that might often be of use to this sort of question. In fact, the comments even list the sequence of [partial sums of the original sequence](http://oeis.org/A006520) - exactly what you are asking about (though you could surely also find this by calculating the first few partial sums and searching for them).

In the comments *there*, we find out a pair of recurrence relations for $b$:
$$b(2n)=2b(n)+n$$
$$b(2n+1)=2b(n)+n+1$$
which gives an extremely efficient way of computing it - for instance, the sum of the first $9$ terms is:
\begin{align*}b(9)&=b(2\cdot 4 + 1)\\&=2b(4)+4+1\\&=2b(2\cdot 2)+5\\&=2(2b(2)+2)+5\\&=4b(2\cdot 1)+9\\&=4(2b(1)+1)+9\\&=8b(1)+13\\&=21\end{align*}
where we note on the last step that $b(1)=1$. The trick here is that we can always rewrite whatever is inside $b$ as either $2n$ or $2n+1$, halving its size at each step - and you can check that this really does equal $1+2+1+4+1+2+1+8+1$

While you won't find justification of this on OEIS, knowing the answer makes finding justification much easier: note that $a(2n)=2a(n)$, so the sum of the terms of $a$ at positions $2,4,\ldots,2n$ is twice the sum of the terms at $1,2,\ldots,n$ (which is $b(n)$) - hence is $2b(n)$. The terms at the odd positions are all $1$ - and there are $n$ or $n+1$ of them below $2n$ or $2n+1$ respectively.

---

**Way 2:** Try to express it in terms of something simpler.

Another way to look at this is to note that it's "mostly" periodic, with a few exceptions - or, even more formally, that you can look at it as "mostly $1$, with some $2$'s added, and then some $4$'s added on top of $2$'s and so on...". More formally, let's consider an array where, on the first row, we write all ones. Then, we start a new row, every other entry of which is $1$. If we sum those rows, we'd get $1,2,1,2,1,2,\ldots$. To correct this, we add a third row, every fourth entry of which is $2$ - and if we add that on we get $1,2,1,4,1,2,1,4,\ldots$ - we then continue adding a $4$ every $8$ columns to fix it further - then an $8$ every $16$ columns, a $16$ every $32$ columns, and so on until we've generated enough of our sequence:
$$\begin{array}\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \end{array}$$
See how the sums of columns here are the entries of $a$. However, the sum of $n$ terms of any row is easy to figure out - clearly, the sum of $n$ terms of the first row is $n$. The second row has $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ non-zero terms (where we use the floor function which rounds down its argument to the next integer) - each of which is $1$, so contributes $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ in total. Then, the next row has $\lfloor n/4\rfloor$ non-zero terms, which are each $2$, so which contributes $2\lfloor n/4\rfloor$ to the sum. Continuing analogously, we will find that the sum of the first $n$ terms of the original sequence - which is the sum of the sums of the rows is:
$$n + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{k-1}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor$$
where you only need to take this sum up to the last $k$ so that $2^k \leq n$, since the remaining terms after that are all zero.

---

**Addendum:** It might be worth noting that this function is pretty easy to describe on the large scale - the sum of the first $2^n-1$ terms is $n2^{n-1}$, which can be seen inductively by noting that the terms $1$ through $2^n-1$ are the same as those from $2^n+1$ to $2^{n+1}-1$ and the term at $2^n$ is just $2^n$ - and it actually looks more and more like a smooth curve the more you zoom out (though, note that the slope of the line that it looks like changes) - for instance, even the first 511 partial sums look pretty linear:

[image: A plot of the first 511 partial sums, looking pretty much linear]

There's some small scale variation, but the function acts basically like $\frac{1}2 n\log_2(n)$ - here's that function overlaid on the prior plot:

[image: A plot of the first 511 partial sums along with the curve n log(n)]

Some more analysis can give that the deviations from this curve are actually quite small - their ratio tends to $1$ - but there's probably not a lot of hope for a much better representation since the deviations have some fractal nature. You could likely come up with some way to do this involving writing $n$ in binary and doing something weird to the bits - but that's largely just another way to encode the sorts of sums and recurrences that appear with this sort of sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The $k$-th term is $\gcd(k,2^k)$, so the sum up to $n$ is $$\sum_{k=1}^n \gcd(k,2^k)$$

It can also be calculated as $$n+\sum _{k=1}^n 2^{k-1} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor$$

No closed form is known for the sum, i think probably there isn't one.